# ResultSet is empty, but it shouldn't be

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

There must be something extremely subtle that I am missing.

I have a class called `LogRecord`.  It has a members `String _pk1` and `String _userID`.  I get `_pk1` from a log file, then I use `_pk1` to query a database and look up `_userID`.

The code that I am using to achieve this:

```
private void setUserID() throws Exception
{
    String userID = "";
    if(_pk1.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        _userID = "";
        return;
    }
    java.sql.Statement statement = _connection.createStatement();

    String userIDQuery = "select user_id from users where pk1 = '" + _pk1.trim() + "'";

    java.sql.ResultSet userIDRS = statement.executeQuery(userIDQuery);
    query = userIDQuery; //edit

    if(userIDRS.next())
    {
        userID = userIDRS.getString("user_id");
        userIDRS.close();
    }
    else
    {
        userID = "query failed";
    }

    _userID = userID;
    userIDRS.close();

    statement.close();
}
```

In practice, I have an `ArrayList` of these `LogRecord`s and they are bound to a `TableView` JavaFX control.  I can see that this query is only returning a result about 25% of the time.  (I set the `_userID` to `query failed` in the case where  `_pk1` was not blank so that I could identify cases where the query *should* have returned a `userID`.

To further debug, I added this code to the `TableView`'s `click()` method so that I could examine the suspicious records.

```
private void tableRightClick(MouseEvent event) {
    LogRecord selectedLogRecord = tblRecords.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    //System.out.println(selectedLogRecord.getLogRecord());
    System.out.println("User's PK1:    " + selectedLogRecord.getPK1());
    System.out.println("Username:      " + selectedLogRecord.getUserID());
    System.out.println("User query:    " + selectedLogRecord.query);
}
```

I can tell from the output that `_pk1` is indeed being captured correctly and that the query being executed *is* correct.  (And, as I mentioned, it works about 25% of the time.)

An example of the console output when I click the suspicious record:

```
User's PK1:    459498
Username:      query failed
User query:    select user_id from users where pk1 = '459498'
```

If I copy the query and paste it into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it returns the correct userID.  (Thus, I *should* be getting something in the `ResultSet`.)

I hope that somebody can explain why I am getting empty resultsets most of the time.

I am using sqljdbc4, JDK 8, and SQLServer 2008 R2.

Comment: Note that the query that you are printing is probably not the query that you are executing. You are only assigning `query = userIDQuery` in case there was a `next()`, not when it fails!

Comment: I pasted old code there.  Sorry.  The output came from the now-edited code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a preparedStatement and bind the parameters correctly. The error can be produced because of the type of the column pk1.

Look which type of column is pk1 and use the pertinent set.

```
    String userIDQuery = "select user_id from users where pk1 = ?";
    java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = _connection.prepareStatement(userIDQuery);
    statement.setString(1, _pk1.trim());
```

Comment: Good idea on calling `trim()`. Though 0 should be 1.

Comment: I was very hopeful that this would work, but I am getting the exact same results.  But, `PreparedStatement` seems to be a better object to work with in general and I will use it from now on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The original code closes twice, and the exception handling is suspicious. On an exception no close is done. Try the following.

```
private void setUserID() throws Exception {
    if (_pk1.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        _userID = "";
        return;
    }
    String userIDQuery = "select user_id from users where pk1 = ?";
    try (PreparedStatement statement = _connection.prepareStatement(userIDQuery)) {
        statement.setString(1, _pk1);
        try (ResultSet userIDRS = statement.executeQuery()) {
            String userID;
            if (userIDRS.next()) {
                userID = userIDRS.getString("user_id");
                //query = userIDQuery + " | " + _pk1;
            } else {
                userID = "query failed";
            }
            _userID = userID;
        } // userIDRS.close();
    } // statement.close();
}
```

Maybe catch and rethrow the exception, logging it.

Comment: I have been handling the exceptions outside the method, using a simple `printStackTrace()`.  I do not see any exceptions.  But, yes, I should have the `close()` statements in the `finally` block of a try-catch in the method.  Thank you!